# PayPal experiencing IPN Posting issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Anybody experiencing IPN intermittent issue? I am getting no IPN message posted for certain transactions. Sometimes it is posted sometimes not. When this will be resolved?

Comment: Post-*ing*. 'Postage' is what you pay to the post-office.

Comment: Sorry about that. I mean Messages were not being delivered. I could n't locate the IPN message in IPN History it prevents me to do resend the IPN from IPN history

Comment: Have you check if your IPN was correctly configured?

Comment: Yes it has been correctly configured. Lets say 5 Orders, 3 Orders IPN received successfully, 2 Orders  IPN messages lost. It should be with PayPal issue. They have mentioned this issue only in PayPal sandbox but seems occuring it in Live PayPal

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the IPN History in PayPal to see if it shows the IPNs were sent for the transactions you're questioning?  In most cases when people say "IPN isn't sending" it really is but there's a problem with the script.

For example, say you have 5 transactions and only 3 worked like you mentioned.  It could be special characters (eg. a name like O'Reilly) in the data that your script isn't processing correctly causing it to fail.

Again, you need to check IPN History, also check your web server logs, PHP error logs, etc.

All of this is outlined in detail in this article I wrote about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).

Comment: I have checked IPN History. There were not IPN Messages generated itself. No IPN Postback to my server .Transaction was success.There is an issue with PayPal side. It has been fixed a day ago. Intermittent problem is not happening now

Comment: can you tell me how you got that fixed ?  What was the issue in PayPal ?  I'm having trouble with zero IPN's in PayPal history also.

Comment: I didn't do anything. Clearly it was an outage. Have received those IPNs back after a week

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue you described, regarding 5 payments the 18th: my system processed several IPN calls that day, but some went missing.

No related problems the months before, no problems the 2 weeks after.

Spent a considerable time searching for possible causes on my side, but I found nothing; even in case of a network issue, PayPal not receiving back the 200 is required to re-try the IPN calls.

It was clearly a PayPal bug, but I was not able to find any status issue report, only single developers ranting about that event, very unprofessional.

I would use just Stripe, but final customers are used to PayPal and ask for it :(